# Calculating heat index using weathermetrics package - wrong results

Tags: r, weather

I am trying to calculate heat index from temperature and relative humidity that are in data frame 'weather'. To calculate it, the package weathermetrics is used.

My code is following:

```
weather$heat_index <- heat.index(t = weather$temperature_outdoor_celsius, 
rh = weather$humidity_perc, temperature.metric = 'celcius', output.metric = 'celcius', round = 10)
```

However, the package returns values that are identical with temperature, when it should return different values.

If I apply it to a specific example,

```
> heat.index(t = 12, rh = 70, temperature.metric = 'celcius', 
output.metric = 'celcius', round = 10)
    [1] 12
```

the results is 12 Celcius. However, the result should be 11 Celcius, according to a webpage that the package lists as a source of the algorithm the package uses (http://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/html/heatindex.shtml). It seems that the function simply returns the value of the temperature instead of processing it in any way.

Is the problem in my code or with the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have mistyped a letter.  If you use `'celsius'` rather than `'celcius'` for the metric options, it will work correctly.  Using this in your example below, a result of 11 is returned.

```
heat.index(t = 12, rh = 70, temperature.metric = 'celsius', 
output.metric = 'celsius', round = 10)
>[1] 11.1
```